# How to control cell editing in jXTable

Tags: java, swing, swingx

how can I be able to make some cells editable and others not editable in a JXTable?
I am retrieving information from a database that I want to map into a table. 
Some of the information is so critical that I would not like users to tamper with. The cells that are not editable do not show any mapped information.

You could ask why I am not using jTable instead of jXTable but I was anxious to use swingx rather than the usual swing.

The code below works when using jTable (javax.swing.JTable) but when I implement it on jXTable, the uneditable columns do not display information.

```
jXTable1 = new org.jdesktop.jXTable(){

    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class,java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
    };
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {false, true, true, true};

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit [columnIndex];
    }
};
```

Comment: AFAICT the `TableModel.isCellEditable` implementation of the `TableModel` is called as well. Check in your setup whether this returns true for editable cells.